# How Do i create Facebook like, like system using this code for Register users

Tags: php

Please Help Me For This Code I Have Already Asked Help For This Code But I Couldn't Get Help From Any One So My Problem is
I Want Likes and Unlikes for Every Register user and also want to check that no same(login user) user should like multiple times for that register user

I have table `user`which has user Data and another table `likes` which has fields  1.`userID` 2.`status_id` 3.`like` 4.`un-like`

I have also Confusion in My `WHERE` Clause and Stored `$userID` Varaiable Please help For That also

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../config.php');
$userID = intval($_REQUEST['userID']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

$like       = $row['like'];
$unlike     = $row['un-like'];
if($_POST)
{   
    if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['op']) == 'like')
    {
        $update = "`like`=`like`+1";
    }
    if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['op']) == 'un-like')
    {
        $update = "`un-like`=`un-like`+1";
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE likes SET $update WHERE userID ='".$userID."'");
    echo 1;
    exit;   
}
?>
<div class="grid">
<span id="status"></span><br>
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $like; ?>" class="button_like" id="likeBtn" />
<input type="button" value="<?php echo $unlike; ?>" class="button_unlike" id="unlikeBtn" />
</div>
```

Comment: You could add another query before the insert/update query to check if an user with a given status id has liked or unliked someone. This way you can still add multiple likes or dislikes by the same person in one table in the future. I would assume it is one-2-many relationship.

Comment: And please switch to PDO for data persistence. It is much safer in comparison to mysql(i) queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can take different approach to implement this. One way would be to configure `UNIQUE KEY` `Index` to your `likes` table on the fields `userID` and `status_id`, and then modify the `UPDATE` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type query. This will let you add a new record if not liked/disliked already and update the fields if the `like` record was already inserted.

Steps to implement this:

### Step 1:

Add a `UNIQUE KEY` index on the fields `userId` and `status_id`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX userId_statusId ON `likes` (`userId`, `status_id`)
```

### Step 2:

Modify your `UPDATE` query to something like below

```
INSERT INTO `likes` (`userId`, `status_id`, `like`, `un-like`) VALUES ($userID, $statusId, 1, 0)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `like`= VALUES(`like`),
    `un-like` = VALUES(`un-like`);
```

Note that I have added `status_id` to the query which you are not factoring in your code. You need to pass it in to this page like `userId`.

Also the `like` and `un-like` field is hardcoded in my query. You can make them dynamic in your `IF` blocks.

#### More reads:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

#### Your final code would look something like this

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../config.php');
$userID = intval($_REQUEST['userID']);
$statusId = intval($_REQUEST['statusID']);

if($_POST)
{   

    $like = 0;
    $unlike = 0;

    if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['op']) == 'like')
    {
        $like = 1;
    }
    if(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['op']) == 'un-like')
    {
        $unlike = 1;
    }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `likes` (`userId`, `status_id`, `likes`, `un-like`) VALUES ($userID, $statusId, $like, $unlike)
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                    `likes`= VALUES(`likes`),
                    `un-like` = VALUES(`un-like`);");
    echo 1;
    exit;   
}
?>
```

Comment: Quick note: "The effects are not identical for an InnoDB table where a is an auto-increment column. With an auto-increment column, an INSERT statement increases the auto-increment value but UPDATE does not."

Comment: Yes true. If thats an issue he can use `REPLACE` instead.. or break it down to 2 queries..